# How to properly convert char to int in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, char, int

I'm getting a unique issue that I haven't experienced before when converting char to int in c++.

I am iterating through a string of integers called total_line which reads as:

```
1526
```

I'm trying to convert every other char into an int and here is my code:

```
cout << total_line[i+1] <<endl;
int d = total_line[i+1] <<endl;
cout << d << endl;
i++;
```

My output is strangely this:

```
5
53
6
54
```

I'm not sure why 5 is being converted to int 53 and 6 is being converted to int 54.

Comment: You have not shown enough code.  Show us the declaration of `total_line`, how it is initialized, and the value of variable `i`.

Comment: The char is coming in as ASCII, essentially. `'5' == 53`. Look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: You are confusing numbers (like five, the number of fingers on my hand) with representations of numbers, like the digit "5" (a symbol that looks a lot like the letter "S").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, characters are actually represented as numbers which are mapped to a character table. The number-to-character map differs depending on the chosen charset, *e.g.*, for US-ASCII the characters `'1'` and `'2'` correspond to the numbers 49 and 50 ([see here for the full US-ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart)).

To convert the string representation of a number into a signed integer use [**`std::stoi`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (since C++11).

The following snippet will chop up the string into its individual digits and use `std::stoi` to convert them into numbers, respectively.

```
for (std::string::size_type i = 0, n = total_line.size(); i != n; ++i) {
    int d = std::stoi(total_line.substr(i, 1));

    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Using the standard-library function `std::stoi` has the advantage of working regardless of character encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (man ascii on linux)

```
     Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
     ---------------------
     060   48    30    0
     061   49    31    1
     062   50    32    2
     063   51    33    3
     064   52    34    4
  -> 065  |53|   35   |5|
  -> 066  |54|   36   |6|
     067   55    37    7 
     070   56    38    8 
     071   57    39    9
```

So you can see that the reason why 5 is converted to 53 and 6 to 54, is because the **decimal** value of the **char** '5' is not 5 but 53 (same with 6).

If you want to convert char to int try something like this:

```
int d = total_line[i] - '0';
```

I won't recommend you this one :

```
int d = total_line[i] - 48;
```

Because of [portability](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man5/ascii.5.asp)(thanks to Pete Becker), and not everybody know the decimal value of '0' and used directly '0' is more understandable I think.

Answer (score 1):

This line looks very strange:

```
int d = total_line[i+1] <<endl;
```

What is the stream `operator<<` and `endl` doing there?

Why not simply do this?

```
int d = total_line[i+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from position `i` instead of `i+1` and also there was an extra `endl` in the second line. The values you get is the `ASCII` value of the characters you try to read. In order to convert them to `int` you need to subtract the ASCII value of '0' from it. And also if you are operating in a `for` loop you don't need to increment `i` explicitly. That is maybe the reason you skip characters

This may help:

```
cout << total_line[i] <<endl;
int d = total_line[i];
cout << d - '0' << endl;
```